# Using only imageview in a row of listview to start a new intent

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to make listview with multiple items in a row, which contains  imageview and textview . Now I want to access only the imageview of a row of a listview and then use it start a new intent by clicking it.
Here is my main activity :

```
public class MTCRichGraphicsActivity extends Activity {
int ELEMENT_COUNT = 1;
int position=0;
ImageButton bAddView;
ImageView bEventPage;
int r =0 ;   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bAddView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bNewEvent);
    bEventPage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivEvent);
    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3d);

    bAddView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    List<String> element = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.bNewEvent :
                //String[] elements = new String[ELEMENT_COUNT];
                //for (int i = 0; i< ELEMENT_COUNT; i++) {
                    //elements[i] = String.valueOf(i);
                    element.add(String.valueOf(ELEMENT_COUNT++));
                //}
                final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MTCRichGraphicsActivity.this,element);
                //list.setScrollY(currentPosition);
                //list.setTranslationY(currentPosition);
                list.setDivider( null ); 
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setTranscriptMode(1);
                list.setStackFromBottom(true);
                //ELEMENT_COUNT = ELEMENT_COUNT + 1;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                         
            }

        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            bEventPage.setFocusable(false);
            bEventPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent("de.inovex.mtc.EventsPage");
                    startActivity(i);   
                }
            });

        }

    });

}
```

}

Now here bEventPage is an ImageView , when I click on any listview row whole of row gets highlighted and gives me a null pointer exception , but the imageview is not clicked and the new activity does not start.
Here is my adapter class :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final List<String> mItems;
TextView t;
ViewHolder holder;
public MyAdapter(Activity c,List<String> objects) {
    mInflater = c.getLayoutInflater();
    mItems = objects;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView t;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent,false);
}
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    holder.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.t3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    holder.t4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    holder.bEventPage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivEvent);
    holder.t1.setText("Title"+position);


    //((ImageView)convertView).setTextAlignment(1);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

So please tell me how to only use the imageview of a row to start a new intent according to its position in listview?

Comment: You can add `onClickListener` for your `holder.bEventPage`

Comment: @RajeshCP I have done it in my main activity ,  but i cannot do this in adapter class because startActivity is undefined for my adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

Add the listener to the image view in the adapter..and remove it from the list item listener

```
Activity activity;

public MyAdapter(Activity c,List<String> objects) {
   mInflater = c.getLayoutInflater();
   mItems = objects;
   activity = c;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
TextView t;
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent,false);
}
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
holder.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
holder.t3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
holder.t4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
holder.bEventPage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivEvent);
holder.t1.setText("Title"+position);


holder.bEventPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent("de.inovex.mtc.EventsPage");
                activity.startActivity(i);   
            }
        });

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I cannot do this because here startActivity(i) is undefined for myadapter class . startActivity is defined only for Activity class , but cannot extend it as I have already extended BaseAdapter class .

Comment: you already passing the activity to your adapter, use it, check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can set onClick listener onImageView in GetView method of  MyAdapter

Comment: I cannot do that because i want to a new intent to start their and startActivity(intent) is undefined for my adapter class